# How to stop Enter key press form submitting

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms

I want to **press enter key** so that the form is **not submitted**, just click on the submit button and the form will be submitted in **ReactJS**

```
const handleSubmit = (data) ={ 
}

<form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
  <label>
    Name:
    <input type="text" name="name" />
  </label>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is apply an `onKeyPress` handler to your `form` and if the value of the key that has been pressed is `Enter`, prevent the default behaviour (submit).

```
<form
  onSubmit={handleSubmit}
  onKeyPress={(e) => {
    e.key === "Enter" && e.preventDefault();
  }}
>
  <label>
    Name:
    <input type="text" name="name" />
  </label>
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Note that you will likely also want to prevent the default for behaviour when your form is submitted, otherwise you'll likely get a page refresh.

```
const handleSubmit = (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
}
```

To get the value of your `name` input, you would do the following:

```
const handleSubmit = (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();

  console.log(event.target.name.value);
}
```

The same principle applies for any other fields you might have in the `form`.

Functioning [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/optimistic-gagarin-sslr3s?file=/src/App.tsx) example.

Comment: OnSubmit is executed when enter button is pressed, I want only submit button click onSubmit to be executed

Comment: @TanvirAhmed I linked the wrong CodeSandbox. I have updated my answer to include a link to the correct example.

Answer (score 0):

You can change your handleSubmit function like this:

```
const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
 }
```

`e.preventDefault()` this prevent the default behaviour of the form and all the events related to that.

Comment: onSubmit is executed when enter button is pressed, I want only submit button click onSubmit to be executed

Answer (score -2):

You can do this without using a form tag and store the input values in a state

```
const handleSubmit = () ={


}


<div>
  <div>
    Name:
  <input type="text" name="name" />
  </div>
  <input onClick={handleSubmit} value="Submit" />
</div>
```